# Copy and replace multiple files (with their full path) from one directory to another directory's corresponding paths

Tags: windows, file, cmd, directory, copy-paste

Say I have two folders : SOURCE and DEST

I have been provided with **relative path** of bunch of files of **SOURCE**. e.g

```
SOURCE/A/B/C/file1.cpp
SOURCE/A/B/D/file2.cpp
SOURCE/M/B/G/file3.cpp
...
```

to replace the corresponding files in **DEST** directory

```
DEST/A/B/C/file1.cpp
DEST/A/B/D/file2.cpp
DEST/M/B/G/file3.cpp
...
```

Can I achieve this with minimal effort using command prompt?

FYI, usually I need to repeatedly go back and forth from SOURCE to DEST to copy each individual file, which is very time consuming and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

There is [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) utility, which can help you to do what you want:

```
robocopy <Original Folder> <Destination Folder> /mir
```